# Making a 'quiz-construction' with arrays

Tags: python

I'm building a simple 'quiz-program'. Code here:

```
import random

wordList1 = []
wordList2 = []

def wordAdd():
    wordNew1 = str(input("Add a word to your wordlist: "))
    wordNew2 = str(input("Add the translation to this word: "))
    if wordNew1 != "exit":
        wordList1.append(wordNew1)
        wordAdd()
    elif wordNew2 != "exit":
        wordList2.append(wordNew2)
        wordAdd()
    else:
        exercise()

def exercise():
    q = random.choice(wordList1)
    a = wordList2
    if q[] == a[]:
        print("Correct!")
    else:
        print("Wrong!")

wordAdd()
```

I'm trying to check the wordList1-number and compare it with the wordList2-number.
Now I didn't expect the def exercise to work but I can't find the solution to let it work...
I know about the dictionary-thing in Python but I would like to know wether such a array-construction is possible in Python.

Could someone help me with this?

Thanks in advance!    Sytze

Comment: You should use a loop to check the exit condition instead of a recursive call

Comment: yes its possible ... probably even easy ... it looks like your indentation is wrong ... what is wrong with this code? what error does it give you? or incorrect result and the expected result

Comment: It looked like the code was pasted into the post correctly indented but it didn't come out properly for some reason

Comment: The error is invalid syntax. if q[] == a[] doesn't seem to work..

Comment: q[] is nothing ... what is it supposed to be? do you just want `q==a` (which I dont think is possible since q is a string, but a is a whole list of strings)? what is excersize() meant to do?

Comment: Excersize should check wether a word == to its translation

Comment: You should use a dictionary to store words and translations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played with your code a little. I'm not sure I perfectly understand your question, but I made it working the way I thought it needs to work. I added some comments to make it clear what I did.

I tried to stick with your basic concept (except the recursion), but I renamed a lot of things to make the code more readable.

```
import random

words = []
translations = []

def add_words():
    # input word pairs until the user inputs "exit"
    print('\nInput word and translation pairs. Type "exit" to finish.')
    done = False
    while not done:
        word = raw_input("Add a word to your wordlist: ")
        # only input translation, if the word wasn't exit
        if word != "exit":
            translation = raw_input("Add the translation to this word: ")
        if word != "exit" and translation != "exit":
            # append in pairs only
            words.append(word)
            translations.append(translation)
        else:
            done = True

def exercise():
    # excercising until the user inputs "exit"
    print("\nExcercising starts. ")
    done = False
    while not done:
        # get a random index in the words
        index = random.randrange(0, len(words))
        # get the word and translation for the index
        word = words[index]
        translation = translations[index]
        # ask the user
        answer = raw_input('Enter the translation for "%s": ' % word)
        if answer == "exit":
            done = True
            print("\nGoodbye!")
        elif answer == translation:
            print("Correct!")
        else:
            print("Wrong!")

add_words()
exercise()
```

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful, it's exactly what I was trying to make.